# Encoding apostrophe in GET API request via "HttpUtility.UrlEncode" and "Uri.EscapeDataString" gives error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, encoding

I am making a GET request from postman and I am expecting list of tables in return:
Following is the URI: `https://XYZ/api/Sam's Club Operations Executive P&L Report DS/Tables`.

This request throws an error as we have an apostrophe in the URI i.e., **Sam's**.

I tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode and Uri.EscapeDataString and while debugging i can see the **'** of **Sam's** being encoded to **Sam%27s** and URI looks like `"Sam%27s%20Club%20Operations%20Executive%20P%26L%20Report%20DS"`.

However, when i am trying to open a connection, I am thrown with exception. My connection string Catalog field looks like: `Catalog=Sam%27s%20Club%20Operations%20Executive%20P%26L%20Report%20DS;`.

The exception thrown is:

> {"Either the database 'Sam%27s%20Club%20Operations%20Executive%20P%26L%20Report%20DS' does not exist,
> or you do not have permissions to access it.\r\n\r\n
> Technical Details:\r\nRootActivityId: f626f5b7-b8ed-4697

I am using basic authentication and I am sending correct username and password with each request. How can I overcome this exception.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with HTTP, ASP.NET Core or encoding. The service code failed to decode the URL. This points to a huge security vulnerability as well - the service is using the input without verifying it. Imagine what would happen if someone encoded `someDb; drop table users--` in the URL. If that part of the URL is meant to represent a database, the service shouldn't even accept an invalid name. It should return a 404 at least

Comment: In any case there's nothing you can fix on the client side. The encoding isn't wrong. The service is essentially broken. You'll have to post the service code so people can help fix it

Answer (score 0):

Encode the URI as the following to make the API call:
`$"\"" + Convert.ToString(WHATEVERURISTRING) + $"\";";`